# Twitter integration in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I integrated twitter in my app through oauth engine. When opening the twitter view its displays the twitter login page by default. But that screen not going without login into twitter. When I want to quit that page that can't possibly goback to the previous view. How can I solve this?

Comment: I see you've asked 10 question here on SO. Hopefully you've gotten some good/helpful answers. If so, you can select the outlined check mark next to the best answer to "accept" it. This will alert future users to the answer that solved the problem, and it rewards the user who took the time to answer your question with 15 reputation points (you also get 2 points in the process). To read more about how the reputation system on SO works, check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I think you working with the example code which u took by googling.As per my knowledge, One example code was designed like until otherwise you give twitter credential, it will show twitter login page.
You just change logic as per your need and do your job.

Comment: ya.iam working with example code.In my page displayed only after login to the twitter otherwise its not go back to the my page without login to the twitter.how to rectify this.

Comment: they have written logic like tat..For better understanding see the - (void)viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated { } method of TwitterRushController